# Sorting nested lists in python results in TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below nested list (lists of list) called `row_list`:

```py
[
    [
        {
            'text': 'Something',
            'x0': Decimal('223.560')
        },
        {
            'text': 'else',
            'x0': Decimal('350')
        },
        {
            'text': 'should',
            'x0': Decimal('373.736')
        },
        {
            'text': 'be',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600')
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            'text': 'here',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600')
        }
    ]
]
```

I am trying to sort all inner list by the `x0` key:

```py
row_list = sorted(row_list, key=lambda x:x['x0'])
```

However, above gives me the error:

> **TypeError:** list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I've tried using `itemgetter` as well:

```py
row_list = sorted(row_list, key=itemgetter('x0'))
```

But that gives me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a nested list. if you want to create a new list:

```
row_list = [list(sorted(item, key=lambda x: x["x0"])) for item in row_list]
```

which produces

```
[[{'text': 'be', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
  {'text': 'Something', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
  {'text': 'else', 'x0': Decimal('350')},
  {'text': 'should', 'x0': Decimal('373.736')}],
 [{'text': 'here', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}]]
```

if you want to keep the original list you could also sort inline instead of creating a new list:

```
for sublist in row_list:
     sublist.sort(key=lambda x: x["x0"])
```

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you. Wasn't aware that I had to iterate within the `sorted` method. Just a quick question - can I still name the list `row_list` instead of `srt`, even though I am referencing it in the sorted method?

Comment: sure, you can keep the name. changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from decimal import Decimal
l = [
    [
        {
            'text': 'Something',
            'x0': Decimal('223.560')
        },
        {
            'text': 'else',
            'x0': Decimal('350')
        },
        {
            'text': 'should',
            'x0': Decimal('373.736')
        },
        {
            'text': 'be',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600')
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            'text': 'here',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600')
        }
    ]]

for i in l:
    i.sort(key=lambda x:x['x0'])

print(l)
```

output

```
    [[{'text': 'be', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')},
  {'text': 'Something', 'x0': Decimal('223.560')},
  {'text': 'else', 'x0': Decimal('350')},
  {'text': 'should', 'x0': Decimal('373.736')}],
 [{'text': 'here', 'x0': Decimal('21.600')}]]
```